# Colorbox images in grid

Tags: 7, media

I installed colorbox module and I'm showing images as thumbnails. Each image is in on new line. Is it possible to set it that images will be in the grid similar as [here](http://www.malagronda.it/en/photos-country-house-umbria/holiday-apartment)?

I have exactly the same settings as [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uY5KH6Ym-tA) but don't see any settings to view images as grid, but I have a feeling I saw this somewhere else, but don't remember where.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS rules to position the images like you want.

Another options would be to use views to display the images, which has built in support for displaying items in a grid.

If you want a more detailed answer, you should provide more info in your question.

Comment: I have exactly the same settings as [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uY5KH6Ym-tA) but don't see any settings to view images as grid, but I have a feeling I saw this somewhere else, but don't remember where.

Comment: @xralf I'm not going to watch a 10 min video to figure out what settings you have. Do a SS.

Comment: field image has the following settings: format : colorbox, Node image style: thumbnail, Colorbox image style: Original image ...

Answer (score -1):

This Drupal module is what solved my issue:

> The [Grid Field Formatter](https://drupal.org/project/grid_field_formatter) module provides a simple way to override the display of multi-value fields to show as a grid/table with a certain number of columns.